# Is there a magic method that gets called when I write **object_identifier?

Tags: python, syntax

Consider the use of the double-star notation in python:

```
instance = NotDictionary(name="", description="")
print( **instance )
```

Is there any way I can control the resulting value of the expression

```
**instance
```

In python?

What methods or what parent must my object have, in order to be treated as a 'expandable' dict in this instance?

For instance, in the same way I can control addition between two objects by the **add** and **radd** methods?